# Flutter fix android:exported error on android project

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I used [this repository](https://github.com/Topfreelancerdeveloperr/flutter_openvpn_library_updated) on `github` on our project and when i try to run or getting `build` application I get this error:

```
android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#de.blinkt.openvpn.LaunchVPN>. 
Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` 
when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined.
```

in that library we have this `AndroidManifest.xml` without `android:exported` element

```xml
<service
    android:name="de.blinkt.openvpn.core.OpenVPNService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.VpnService"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<activity
    android:name="de.blinkt.openvpn.LaunchVPN"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:label="@string/vpn_launch_title"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.Panel">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

the library owner don't added this element on that and this library implemented by this code:

```
implementation 'com.github.Topfreelancerdeveloperr:flutter_openvpn_library_updated:3361996fa1'
```

i think i should fork this project to add this element but i don't know how can i use forked project on `github` in `gradle`

Answer (score 4):

Now when creating new Flutter project, a property `android:exported="true"` is now automatically added in **AndroidManifest.xml**. I faced similar issue with my one of old project during building. I just added it in `<activitiy>` of AndroidManifest and it worked fine.

Your `<activity` block should look like this.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Comment: i have it on my `activity` block before

Comment: ovpn is missing this property from their manifest. So not only on your project but you need to add this propery in opvn lib as well.

Comment: do you know how can i install library from github repository?